# fullcalendar break

Tags: php, fullcalendar, break

I am using fullcalendar in conjunction with qtip for an events based site (php), and I have it working pretty well.

I am struggling a bit with a change I want to make.

In my record set I am retrieving a location - which is free text from an html editor.

This is fine with basic text and I am adding slashes to escape apostrophes in any text etc.

However, if there is a line break in the text, the page will not render, and when debugging the js I get error `unexpected token ILLEGAL`

I have tried strip_tags function, which seems to remove the offending 
 tags, but the page still will not render, As soon as I remove the br tag, it works ok.

I am building up a string from my record set and displaying it as follows...

```
    <?php $eventlist = "";?>
    <?php do { ?>
    <?php $eventlist = $eventlist."{title:    '".addslashes($row_rsevents['EventName'])."', start: '". $row_rsevents['EventDate']."', starttime: '". $row_rsevents['StartTime']."', endtime: '". $row_rsevents['EndTime']."', dateF: '". $row_rsevents['EventDateF']."', className: '". $row_rsevents['CSSTag']."', host: '".addslashes($row_rsevents['HostDescription'])."', eventtype: '". $row_rsevents['EventTypeDescription']."', url: '"."event_detail.php?EventID=". $row_rsevents['EventID']."', description: '". addslashes(strip_tags($row_rsevents['Location']))."'},"; ?>
    <?php } while ($row_rsevents = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsevents)); ?>
    <?php $eventlist = rtrim($eventlist,',');//remove the trainling comma ?>


    ...events: [
    <?php echo $eventlist; ?>
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell how your final json-encoded array looks like, but you don't need to do the encoding by hand; just build your event array (as you do in your `fetch` loop) and then `echo json_encode($evarray)` which should take care of whatever chars you put in title, description, etc.

You can also add custom properties ev.line1, ev.line2 and respond to `eventRender(ev, elt...)` replacing the event title, like so: `elt.find(".fc-event-title").html(ev.line1+"<br/>"+ev.line2);`, if you wanted the `br` there.